# VBA Textboxes created at runtime cannot be referenced

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, userform

I have some code that creates a whole line of textboxes at run-time, the textboxes use the dimensions of the pre-established boxes to create a whole line of textboxes each time 'Add Line' is clicked and it looks like this -

[image: The white textboxes are the ones added at run-time once 'Add Line' is clicked]

This is done with the following code -

```
Public Sub AddLine_Click()
Static i As Integer
Dim txtbox As Object


DocNameArr = Array("Type", "Status", "Reference", "Units", "Quantity", "ValidityDate", "IssuingAuthority", "Reason")

AbsoluteHeight = Me.DocType.Top
prevWidth = 0

Dim cCont As Control
contCount = 1

For Each cCont In Me.Controls
If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" And InStr(1, cCont.Name, "Type") = 1 Then
contCount = contCount + 1
End If
Next cCont


     For Each DocName In DocNameArr
     Set txtbox = DocumentsForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", True)
     currTxtbox = "Doc" & DocName
     
     txtboxWidth = DocumentsForm.Controls(currTxtbox).Width
     
            With txtbox
            .Name = DocName & contCount
            .Left = 10.5 + prevWidth
            .Height = 26.25
            .Top = 47.25 + (26.25 * contCount)
            .Width = txtboxWidth
            .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
            .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
            .BorderColor = &H80000000
            End With
            
    prevWidth = prevWidth + txtboxWidth
    Next
End Sub
```

I name the textboxes at runtime as per the code and each separate box in each line of boxes has a number to identify the line and a name to identify the box. This is all fine until I want to save the information that the user enters into the box.

If I reference a textbox directly via name that was created during run-time and as a test insert text directly into it, it drops an Object Required error telling me that the object of that name cannot be found. For example based on the code, I should have a "Type1" box created on the first line, but I can't reference it.

For now, for testing purposes all I've done is reference the textbox directly to see if its accessible via name by doing

```
Type1.Value = "Test"
Type2.Value = "Test"
Type3.Value = "Test"
```

Just trying to parse the word "Test" into any of the textboxes that are created.

How do I save the data of the textbox if its created as above during run-time?

I don't see why it doesn't let me call the textbox via the name its getting allocated at run-time, I output all controls into a msgbox and it comes up with "" for all the run-time named controls? Where am I going wrong here.. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you referencing the textbox? Share that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the Controls collection and pull out the TextBox you want eg

```
Function GetTextBox(sName As String) As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim ctrl As Control
    For Each ctrl In Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            If ctrl.Name = sName Then
                Set GetTextBox = ctrl
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Function
```

... pass the name of the TextBox into this Function and, so long as it exists in the UserForm, it will return the TextBox object to you

Answer (score 1):

Use the controls collection e.g.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 to contCount
     Debug.Print Me.Controls(DocName & contCount).Text
Next
```